# Deploying to Parse.com hosting from continous Integration

Tags: parse-platform

Does anyone know if it's possible to deploy to Parse.com hosting from CloudBees, Travis, or circle?

I'm aware of the commandline tool but I'm not sure how to integrate it with CI or if there is any other way.

Comment: I'm search for a solution too.  At the moment, Parse's idea of deployment seems to be copy and paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution that have worked well for me. Using [travis-ci.com](http://travis-ci.com) you can set it up to work with parse.com and github. Users commit to master branch and the code is auto deployed to Parse.com. Basically your credentials are encrypted using Travis's Ruby script (which can be found here: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/ . Once you're keys are made, you setup a .yml config file that, on travis downloads the parse sdk in a virtual environment, uses the hashed credentials to login to parse and then runs the parse deploy function resulting in a push to parse.

Comment: This is a great repo which has a working example of how it works. It's a little bloaty as there are some more steps in the build script, nonethless [https://github.com/sheki/parse-blog](https://github.com/sheki/parse-blog)